# How to know the X and Y coordinates of a ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview

I want to know the X and Y co-ordinates of a Imageview . I have to click on a single imageview , but on different positions i have to perfrom different tasks.

Kindly suggest me how can i know the X and Y co-ordinates of Imageview.

Sorry , I am not posting any code regarding this.

Comment: X and Y co-ordinates of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnTouchListener has a paramater of event where you can get the x and y of the touch.

Answer (score 1):

`View.getX()` and `View.getY()` will give you the left most and top most pixels on the screen respectively.  Use those in conjunction with `View.getWidth()` and `View.getHeight()` and you got the entire pixel grid that the `ImageView` takes up.

Answer (score 1):

set onTouchListener  ........... then use even.getX() and event.getY() ;

Answer (score 1):

you could  add an OnTouchListener() to image view

```
img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                event.getX()     //cordinates wrt view
                event.getRawX()  //abs cordinates on screen
                                event.getY()     //cordinates wrt view
                event.getRawY()  //abs cordinates on screen
                return false;
            }
        });
```